# Metric for comparing supervised and unsupervised model

Tags: machine-learning, unsupervised-learning, supervised-learning, metric

I'm searching on how to compare (*validate*) a supervised learning model to an unsupervised one.

Let's say I have a supervised model for fault diagnosis which can tell me how accurate it is to predict the test data. So basically the accuracy is calculated from the four kind of output values i.e. True Positive (TP), True Negative (TN), False Positive (FP), False Negative (FN).

I need a metric for unsupervised model so that it can be compared fairly with the supervised model. Hence, I found [Fowlkes-Mallows scores](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#fowlkes-mallows-scores) where it calculates the performance of a supervised (clustering) model with regard to TP, TN, FP, FN, the formula is:

[image: formula]

Therefore, I think I can calculate the FMI scores for the supervised model output.

my questions:

1. Is what I'm doing correct?
2. Is there any other ways to compare the performance of a supervised model to an unsupervised one?

Comment: How do you calculate the TP, FP, TN, and FN for the unsupervised model?

Comment: [sklearn.metrics.fowlkes_mallows_score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.fowlkes_mallows_score.html#sklearn.metrics.fowlkes_mallows_score) and wikipedia [Fowlkes–Mallows index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fowlkes%E2%80%93Mallows_index) shows how to calculate the TP, FP, TN, and FN for clustering model which belongs to unsupervised learning